# Get value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables like this:

Table1
    doc_id (1)
    doc_folder (1010)
    doc_title (invoice 2020)

Table2
    file_id (1)
    file_doc_id (1)
    file_name (invoice.pdf)

Now, i perform a query to get all titles:

```
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    WHERE doc_folder='1010'
```

I'm like to get a file name from Table2 and have result like this:

```
FOLDER | TITLE     | FILE NAME 
1010     invoice     invoice.pdf
```

How to get filename from Table2

TKS ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select table1.*, table2.file_name from table1
inner join table2 on table2.file_doc_id = table1.doc_id
where table1.doc_folder='1010'
```

You can use `table. doc_folder, table.doc_title` instead of `table1.*` if you do not need to fetch all columns from `table1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.file_id, Table2.file_name
FROM            Table1 INNER JOIN
                     Table2 ON Table1.doc_id = Table2.file_doc_id
WHERE        (Table1.doc_folder = '1010')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON file_doc_id = doc_id
WHERE doc_folder='1010'
```

In this case table names don't have to be prefixed, because all columns have different names. However, it is considered good practice to add them, which would look this way:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.file_doc_id = t1.doc_id
WHERE t1.doc_folder='1010'
```